# Driving from Genoa to The Hague with an LPG car

Tags: budget, france, germany, planning, driving

We are a family of 4, two adults + 5 years old + 8 months old. We are traveling to The Hague, Holland from Genoa, Italy. We decided to go by car, and we are trying to calculate costs. So here it goes:

- Is it difficult to find LPG in France or Germany?
- Through which country is it cheaper to drive?

Comment: Check www.viamichelin.com for the alternative routes and their costs.

Comment: I removed the subjective portion of your question; whether it's "best" to take one route or another depends entirely on your objectives (cost? time? scenery? etc).  I think you're only asking for the cheapest route, and you asked that separately, so I think the question's intent is still fully in tact.

Comment: Here's a map of LPG stations in [Germany](http://www.mylpg.eu/stations/germany) and in [France](http://www.mylpg.eu/stations/france)

Comment: @Flimzy But people could provide an overview of the relevant trade-offs (as indeed one comment does below) or mention some issues the OP did not envision. As long as the question is answerable, I don't think we need to react so negatively to any use of the word "best".

Comment: @Annoyed: I don't think you need to continue to post so negatively on the policies of Stack Exchange which are not ours to change. They've given us a site specifically for objectively answerable questions only and we could've used an existing travel forum instead of accepting their terms.

Comment: @hippietrail I do get your general point and it's true that I am sometimes critical of various policies but I don't think it was what I was doing in this case. There is a distinction between the policy (avoiding subjective questions) and mindlessly reacting to specific words (i.e. if there is “best“ in it, let's edit it out or close the question). In fact, I am completely on board with this particular policy, as purely subjective questions are not answerable in my view. But that does not mean we have to use that word stupidly.

Comment: Negatively? Mindlessly? Stupidly? Your words either reveal an agenda or lack of careful thought.

Comment: @hippietrail Why? Is it logically impossible for a word to be used stupidly? If I think that's what's happening how am I supposed to express it? My words merely reveal an opinion, namely that I think this particular word (“subjective”) is often used stupidly. Obviously, I might be ignorant, confused, mistaken or maybe even stupid or insane but I did think about all this quite carefully…

Comment: It's name-calling. If you want to be the instigator of inter-contributor hostilities by throwing the first stone then I refer you first to **[Rule 1: Be nice!](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/870)**. We can respectfully disagree as I'm sure the majority of us do on some point or other here and there. That doesn't mean we should each call one another stupid in comments at regular intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Germany would seem a bit cheaper as, unlike France, there is no toll (for cars) on the main motorway network. As pointed out by @user3470, you could use ViaMichelin to figure out how much a specific route would cost you. Any reasonable route also seems to go through Switzerland and you would have to pay for the motorway there as well but this would not depend on the route as it is a yearly vignette.

For the rest, I think fuel costs would be roughly equal. However, if you do let yourself drive faster in Germany where it is allowed (you don't have to, obviously), it might reduce mileage/increase costs noticeably. If you have a lot of time, you could also stay away from the motorways and avoid tolls. It's also often nicer landscape-wise and possibly cheaper in terms of fuel cost as well but I don't think this would be practical on such a long journey, especially with kids. Comparing food between countries is difficult but if you are on a budget, you should definitely take your lunch with you anyway.

On the other hand, the most direct route through France would also go through Luxembourg, where petrol is still cheaper than in all neighboring countries (albeit perhaps not as much as some years ago). Now, all this is valid for unleaded fuel, I never drove an LPG car. I did notice that it is available (certainly in Luxembourg, generally also in France, Belgium, the Netherlands…) but never paid much attention if it was available everywhere, how much it cost, etc. A quick web search suggests LPG might be 25% cheaper in Luxembourg compared to France.

Comment: If you're in it for the drive and willing to take the time you could consider driving through Austria. The autobahnvignette for Switzerland costs €34,- while Austria has a 10 day vignette at €8,30. It adds nearly 200km  (and nearly 4 hours) to the trip, but you'll still save a bit. For me the main reason to consider this route would not be to save a few euro's, but because it gives you a chance to drive the [Stelvio pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stelvio_Pass) which is a pretty stunning drive (though it might be closed in winter).

Comment: @AVee If you take fuel costs into account, it would be roughly the same I think.

Comment: Toll along that route is all a trade-off between money and time by the way. You can save €10,- between Genoa and Milan, but that will slow you down a lot. You can however easily avoid the Austria vignette by taking the 171 instead of the A12. But avoiding toll in Switzerland is barely possible, and avoiding Switzerland altogether will add a few hours to the trip.

Comment: Yes, that's true as well. Incidentally, avoiding the toll in Switzerland is not too difficult. Just get on the motorway after the border. I did it once, did not feel good about it and have paid every time since but in practice it was very easy. I am told they do checks from time to time but it doesn't seem very common.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to enjoy traffic jams on the German Autobahn

Comment: @user3470 The A4 and A31 in France can compete ;-)

Comment: @Annoyed 200km at 1:10 will be around €16,- for LPG (LPG costs around 80 cents a liter) and the Austria vignette is avoidable on top of that. But it will add a few hours to the trip. (The Stelvio is worth it though ;) )

Comment: No way. The A4 from Strasbourg to Metz is an easy drive. A31 is still much better than A8, A5and alike in Germany

Comment: I drove all of these several times and I can tell you that traffic on the A31 can be very dense. You're right that the A4 is not too bad, I was thinking about the stretch from Basel to Strasbourg, where it's called something else. OTOH, the A5 is nicer now. The A8 should indeed be avoided like the plague but there is no reason to go there on a North-South journey.

Comment: @AVee Thanks for doing the math ;-) You might want to repost all your comments as an answer, they are quite useful.